# ConstraintLayout with growing TextViews claiming equal space if needed

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to in ConstrainLayout have two textviews constrained such that they take 50% of the horizontal space each if they need it, and if they don't the other grows to fill the space.

**A Correct:** When texts are short the textViews do not interfere with eachother.
 [image: equal]

**B Correct:** The short left textView yields space to the longer right one
[image: leftsmall]

**C Correct:** Share horizontal space equally and grow vertically

[image: correct]

**D Incorrect:** Right textView grows on expense of the left textView.

[image: rightlonger]

**E Incorrect:** Right textView grows vertically rather than filling available horizontal space.

[image]

I've tried a lot of things. It think `layout_width="wrap_content"` or `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` is a must since it is the textViews' only way to communicate how much space it wants.

Experimented with:

```
layout_constrainedWidth="true/false"
layout_constraintWidth_default="spread/wrap"
layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1" // with 0dp as width
```

Experimentation mostly with the textViews in a horizontal chain, since there is a symmetry in the problem I think a symmetric solution makes sense.

Has anyone managed this or is it just impossible? I do not know why it behaves as it does with the second element in the chain being 'heavier' than the first one forcing it to be the only one to grow vertically.

Comment: What you simply want is two text views in a chain to adapt according to content (as shown in your correct images)?

Comment: If both text views are larger than 1 line, but one is much longer, do you expect: (a) 50% width each; or (b) balance width until they are the same height?

Comment: @AjahnCharles I expect your (a) choice.

Comment: It's an intriguing question. I think your original examples B & C are 2 distinct logical cases (depending on whether the total text length exceeds 1 line) and that may prevent you finding a trivial (XML) solution. Perhaps someone can offer a solution in Java/Kotlin. I'd personally look for a compromise covering all cases (that's where I was going with the "balanced" choice; though I didn't have a solution for that immediately either). Maybe you could somehow "reserve" some minimum space on either side and then let the views fight for the middle?! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, you have to set the width of the `TextViews` to 0dp. I added a [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier) to the `TextView` at the left so that whenever the right `TextView` needs space, it will take the space of the left `TextView`. Try this code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/text_barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: cha]

Comment: I don't think barriers can be used to achieve the required behaviour. Just try inserting long texts into your textviews and you can see it doesn't constrain the views properly.

Comment: @Adam Oh, I forgot about that. I will work on that and tell you when its updated

Comment: @Adam, I updated it. This time it works! Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm sorry it does not work. The behaviour of the views should be symmetric. Swap the texts between the views and the widths of the views should swap as well. Entering a long text in your first textView makes it fill the entire screen.

Comment: @Adam, sorry I don't know how to solve your problem. I don't know how to make their behavior symmetric. I hope this was still able to help you or serve as a guideline. If I come up with a solution, I will update you.

Answer (score 2):

Barriers is what you are looking for in combination with chaining.

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="start"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"/>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Why is a `barrier` needed? It seems like `constrainedWidth` is important!

Comment: still, this is not answer as @Adam wants.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Constraint layout horizinatal chain property.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#655643"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Dream Destinations sfsd sdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
        tools:text="by Someone, 921 discoveriesdfdsfdsfsdffsfsfsdf" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This do not work. It does not fulfil the requirement as seen in my second picture.

Comment: The short left textView yields space to the longer right one -> this one not fullfill?

Comment: Yes, I added what the code you provided does wrong as an explicit example. Checkout the edit!